# On hyperplanes in subspaces and their relation to superspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Is is possible for a hyperplane with a normal vector in $\mathbb{R^n} \subset \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ to intersect a point with some nonzero $x_{n+1}$ coordinate?

The resulting equation for the plane does not even contain a $n+1$ coordinate which makes it impossible in my opinion.

My text is talking about a vertical hyperplane in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ being generated by a vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ but I find that hard to imagine.

Who's right?

Comment: What do you mean with $\;\Bbb R^n\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}\;$ ?

Comment: @user1: What text, what chapter, what page?

Comment: @DonAntonio That we are in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ and the vector is in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Comment: It's talking about a vertical $n$-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ which _projects_ onto an $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Quite different than what you wrote.

Comment: @quasi which means it can intersect a point in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ with non zero $n+1$ coordinate?

Comment: @quasi I am sorry now I got confused..Can it or cant it have a point on/in it with nonzero $n+1$ coordinate?

Comment: The vertical hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ will certainly have points with a nonzero $x_{n+1}$ coordinate.

Comment: @quasi ofc..now I see it. It can have any coordiante and still make the scalar product behave as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To imagine it, take $n=2$, and consider a vertical hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The projection of $H$ onto the $xy$-plane (regarded as $\mathbb{R}^2$) is a line in the $xy$-plane (which is a hyperplane relative to $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Does that help with the visualization?